# XAJAX - Load all request at same time

Tags: asynchronous, request, load, xajax

I Want XAJAX to laod all request at the same time. Now it loads one request, then the next request loads if the one before is finished. But i want load both at the same time. How can i do this? Defaultmode is allready set on asynchronus.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register a function in synchronous mode like this:

```
$xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION, 'xajaxFunction', array('mode'=>'synchronous'));
```